# Find all values of $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x,y)=e^{\displaystyle{{a\pi x +bt}}}$ satisfies $f_t(x,t)$ =$f_{xx}(x,t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let a and b be constants.

What I did:

$f_x(x,t) = a\pi e^{\displaystyle{{a\pi x +bt}}}$

$f_{xx}(x,t) = a^2\pi^2e^{\displaystyle{{a\pi x +bt}}}$

$f_t(x,t) = be^{\displaystyle{{a\pi x +bt}}}$

Basically I found the first and second partial derivatives with respect to $x$, and the first partial derivative wrt $t$. Now I set the $f_{xx}$ with $f_t$ but am not sure if this is correct, but if it is - I'm not sure how to get values for $a$ and $b$ after rearranging

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close
$$
f_{xx} = a^2\pi^2 f\\
f_t = bf
$$
we have
$$
f_t = f_{xx}  \implies bf = a^2\pi^2 f \to (b-a^2\pi^2)f = 0
$$
so we have
$$
b-a^2\pi^2 = 0 
$$

or
$$
b = a^2\pi^2
$$
this leads to
$$
f(x,t) = \mathrm{e}^{a\pi x +a^2\pi^2 t} = \mathrm{e}^{a\pi(x + a\pi t)}
$$
so you need another condition to fix the $a$ parameter and hence $b$ (or vice versa)

Comment: Ah so we need another condition to actually solve a or b?

Comment: yup you do indeed. typically you need two equations for two unknowns. The original pde is the first so you need another, boundary condition or something.